# I'm unable to reference an uploaded file

Tags: c#, asp.net

Sorry if this is a simple question but I'm still not to competent at coding.  Via ASP.net c#  I upload a file to Uploads with an UploadHandler.ashx which is working fine.  Then I try to reference the file.  Before referencing it I check to see if the file exists with

```
if (File.Exists(filePath))
{
    Do stuff;
}
else
{
    Do other stuff;
}
```

When debugging the filePath is showing as "../Uploads/P3301_5_40_4.bin" which is what I am expecting but the if file exists is returning false.  Am I entering the file path with an incorrect syntax or is there something else I am messing up?  I confirmed the file is there.

Comment: Are you actually using a reference, or the filepath string itself?

Comment: you need to convert the virtual path to a proper Windows file path

Answer (score 1, accepted):

File.Exists is probably looking for the physical path to the file on the server. Try using Server.MapPath which maps the virtual path in your website to the physical path on the server.

```
string physicalPath = Server.MapPath(filePath);
if (System.IO.File.Exists(physicalPath))
{
  // do stuff
}
else
{
  // handle error
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should convert filePath using something like this:

```
filePath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(filePath);
```